# Is it safe to add INDEX to a column in Wordpress database?

Tags: database

I made this custom code that makes Comment into **Review with star-rating**. The star is saved as `comment_karma`.

In the Product Archive page, I want to show text like this: **"25 people 5-starred this"** in each thumbnail.

I can easily get those data with `get_comments()`. But I'm afraid it will put a heavy load on the server since `comment_karma` column isn't INDEX.

> So, will adding INDEX improves the performance? Is it safe?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to answer that question without knowing the exact query and the database structure (if that is non standard).
Generally, it's safe to add indices. If you enable the slow_slog, you can use that in order to find out if the optimization helps (just filter your get_comments() queries, and sum all the execution times). If you do that before and after adding the index, you know if it helped.

Comment: @Christopher thanks for the reply. Didn't know about slow_slog before, will give it a test